# Why is indentation for scrjura different for each paragraph?

Tags: koma-script, indentation, scrjura

I am trying to set up a contract with `scrjura`. Somehow the indentation seems to be different for the start of each paragraph. Why?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,parskip=half]
    {scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter,helvet}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[clausemark=forceboth,
    juratotoc, juratocnumberwidth=2.5em]
    {scrjura}
      

\renewcommand*{\parformat}{% 
    \global\hangindent 2em 
    \makebox[2em][l]{(\thepar)\hfill}\hspace{-0.5em}
} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{contract}
        \Clause{title={Nutzung und Gestaltung}}
        
        Der Mieter verpflichtet sich, die Mietsache einschließlich aller darin enthaltenen Einrichtungen und Gegenstände sowie Gemeinschaftseinrichtungen schonen zu behandeln und Schäden daran zu vermeiden.
        
        Dies beinhaltet eine ausreichende Reinigung (weiteres unter ??), Lüftung und Heizung der Mietsache, insbesondere in Räumen mit einer hohen Anfälligkeit für Feuchtigkeits- und Frostschäden, wie etwa Räume im Dachgeschoss, Küche und Bäder. Der Mieter haftet für Schäden, wenn dies nicht im erforderlichen Umfang geschieht.
        
        Der Mieter ist verpflichtet, das Haus lediglich zu dem im Vertrag vorgesehenen Zweck zu gebrauchen. Er bedarf der Zustimmung, wenn er die Mietsache zu anderen Zwecken gebrauchen will, außer es handelt sich um nicht störende berufliche Tätigkeiten, die nicht nach außen in Erscheinung treten.
        
        Im Übrigen ist die Zustimmung zur gewerblichen Nutzung nur zu erteilen, soweit hierdurch keine größeren Einwirkungen auf andere Mieter, den Vermieter oder die Wohnung entstehen, und sie kann von der Zahlung eines Zuschlags für gewerbliche Nutzung abhängig gemacht werden. 
        
        Bei vertragswidriger Nutzung ist der Vermieter nach Abmahnung zur fristlosen Kündigung berechtigt.
    \end{contract}
\end{document}
```

The start of the text of each paragraph should be the same than all the following lines of the same paragraph.

[image]

Comment: missing `%` (again)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Where? There needs to be an empty line between the paragraphs and adding `%` at the end of a paragraph does not change anything... Adding a `%` to the end of each line of the `\parformat` definition changes things but does not solve the problem...

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't an `enumerate`?

Comment: @Teepeemm no:-)

Comment: @Teepeemm: `scrjura` does add a few neat commands and also make the text much more clearly writable and readable by removing the need to start each line with `\item` as with enumerate.

Comment: @mrCarnivore I guess you've gotten the MWE from here: https://komascript.de/node/1404 . As Markus explained there: terrible hack, don't do it. Paragraphs in contracts are not layouted like enumerations. And I really hope your text is just a dummy.

Comment: @KeksDose: Why do you hope the text is just a dummy? I copied it from a real contract...

Comment: @mrCarnivore Maybe a real contract, but not written by an expert. Section 1 (§ 1) states that the house only may be used for the purposes as described in the contract, but does not describe them. Just as an example. Tenancy law is highly regulated in Germany. Meet your lawyer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear why you need tex primitves rather than a latex list, but

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,parskip=half]
    {scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter,helvet}
\showoutput
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[clausemark=forceboth,
    juratotoc, juratocnumberwidth=2.5em]
    {scrjura}
      

\renewcommand*{\parformat}{% 
    \global\hangindent 2em 
    \makebox[2em][l]{(\thepar)\hfill}% missing % here
} 
\renewcommand*{\parformatseparation}{}


\begin{document}
    \begin{contract}
        \Clause{title={Nutzung und Gestaltung}}
        
        Der Mieter verpflichtet sich, die Mietsache einschließlich aller darin enthaltenen Einrichtungen und Gegenstände sowie Gemeinschaftseinrichtungen schonen zu behandeln und Schäden daran zu vermeiden.
        
        Dies beinhaltet eine ausreichende Reinigung (weiteres unter ??), Lüftung und Heizung der Mietsache, insbesondere in Räumen mit einer hohen Anfälligkeit für Feuchtigkeits- und Frostschäden, wie etwa Räume im Dachgeschoss, Küche und Bäder. Der Mieter haftet für Schäden, wenn dies nicht im erforderlichen Umfang geschieht.
        
        Der Mieter ist verpflichtet, das Haus lediglich zu dem im Vertrag vorgesehenen Zweck zu gebrauchen. Er bedarf der Zustimmung, wenn er die Mietsache zu anderen Zwecken gebrauchen will, außer es handelt sich um nicht störende berufliche Tätigkeiten, die nicht nach außen in Erscheinung treten.
        
        Im Übrigen ist die Zustimmung zur gewerblichen Nutzung nur zu erteilen, soweit hierdurch keine größeren Einwirkungen auf andere Mieter, den Vermieter oder die Wohnung entstehen, und sie kann von der Zahlung eines Zuschlags für gewerbliche Nutzung abhängig gemacht werden. 
        
        Bei vertragswidriger Nutzung ist der Vermieter nach Abmahnung zur fristlosen Kündigung berechtigt.
    \end{contract}
\end{document}
```

---

To answer the question in the title, why the space differs each paragraph.

`scrjura` adds `\nbreakspace` (3.04408 plus 1.82864 minus 0.73364)
you added another space so  a total of around 6pt with 3.6pt stretch and 1.5pt shrink, you compensated with a negative space of 0.5em (why this length?) which is a fixed length 5.47499pt  so you have .5pt plus 3.6pt minus 1.5pt variable space.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works great! I did use an example from a `scrjura` document. Clearly I did not understand it completely. Thanks for helping me along the way.

Answer (score 0):

MWE has probably been copied from here:
https://komascript.de/node/1404

If it had been copied correctly, it would have worked.

```
\makeatletter
% Das Verwenden von \@gobble an dieser Stelle ist ein übler Hack und geht
% davon aus, dass der Wortabstand nach der Nummer unmittelbar nach \parformat
% als einzelne Anweisung eingefügt wird. Das kann bei kleinsten Änderungen von
% scrjura schief gehen! Sicherer wäre deshalb ein entsprechender negativer
% \hspace{...} an der Stelle!
\renewcommand*{\parformat}{%
  \global\hangindent 2em
  \makebox[2em][l]{(\thepar)\hfill}\@gobble
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: So you say the code in my answer was more correct than the answer you posted since I am already using `\hspace{-0.5em}` instead of `\@gobble` and therefore already conform to the suggestion of Markus Kohm? Or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: @mrCarnivore I posted the code from komascript and provided the link. »Your« layout of a contract is a copy of the word makeshift. Word doesn't offer an easy solution to number paragraphs like it is common in contracts and laws in Germany. There is no hanging number like it were a enumeration.

Comment: I tried using a layout that is more readable. With hanging number you mean that there is no indentation of the text after the paragraph number?

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yes, just use the default with `parskip=half` e.g. in the global options.